# Search for all records within X distance of any records in a table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table with a bunch of geographies of hospitals (roughly 100 rows), and another table with a bunch of geographies of something else (tens of thousands of rows). How do I select ALL of the latter records that are within X radius of ANY of the former records?

Comment: please consider improving your question according to this excellent meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ST_DWithin()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) from PostGIS:

```
SELECT *
FROM   whatever w
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM hospital h
   WHERE  ST_DWithin(h.the_geog, w.the_geog, $distance_in_meters)
   );
```

The [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join is not only (probably) fastest, it also avoids duplicates that might come out of similar queries with a plain (`OUTER`) `JOIN`.

You should at least have this **spatial GiST index**:

```
CREATE INDEX ON hospital USING gist (the_geog);
```

Related:

- [PostGIS radius query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120537/3684)